# Data visualization using Maps - which API to choose? - Angular2+Typescript

Tags: angular, maps

Would anyone suggest, what are the best MAP APIs available to build a data visualization project using Angular2(Typescript) to project data using maps?

It should have the following capabilities
zoom (world --> countries --> states --> cities),
hover over,
heatmap,
display plots etc.

Currently looking at D3.js, Google map API, HighCharts. Need to make a decision pretty quickly, hence need your help to make the right decision to choose the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are plenty of options available in the market for the mentioned requirement, I have chosen D3.Js as it wasn't very difficult to implement my requirements and it provides ultra flexibility for custom implementation.